# How to hide header navigation bar on react native navigation on expo?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-navigation-stack

//    import statements

```
const screens = {
    
    home:{
        screen:home,
        navigationOptions: {
            headerShown:false,
          }
      
    }

const homeStack = createStackNavigator(screens);
export default NavigationContainer(homeStack);
```

i have kept the headerShown element as false still the header is visible, pls help..

Comment: please use react-navigation 5.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, I think it's 'screenOptions' instead of "navigationOptions' for using the property 'headerShown'.

Answer (score 0):

It's `navigationOptions: { header: { visible: false } }` and please use react navigation 5